# animate x,y co-ordinate within div

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am getting json data like-->

```
$json = '[
    {
        "vt": "10",
        "at": "0",
        "cor": [
            [47,85,1,0,1,2],
            [181,86,1,1,1,3],
            [99,197,1,0,1,4],
            [116,183,1,2,1,6],
            [83,51,1,3,1,7],
            [180,90,1,4,1,9],
            [88,110,1,5,1,11],
            [83,54,1,6,1,15],
            [83,55,1,6,1,15],
            [83,56,1,6,1,15],
            [83,57,1,6,1,15],
            [83,58,1,6,1,15],
            [83,59,1,6,1,15],
            [83,60,1,6,1,15],
            [83,61,1,6,1,15],
            [83,62,1,6,1,15],
            [83,63,1,6,1,15],
            [83,64,1,6,1,15],
            [83,65,1,6,1,15],
            [83,66,1,6,1,15],
            [83,67,1,6,1,15],
            [83,68,1,6,1,15],
            [83,69,1,6,1,15],
            [83,70,1,6,1,15],
            [83,150,1,6,1,15],
            [83,310,1,6,1,15]
        ],
        "an": "MainActivity"
    }
]';
```

where cor part contain serially as: 
"cor"[x coordinate, y coordinate, orientation, gesture, response, time]

now what i ve animate all those gesture 6 x, ycordinate... how can i do that using jquery animate??

i am trying to animate like this but its not working-->

```
$json=json_decode($json,true);
$coordinate=$json[0]['cor'];

foreach ($coordinate as $key ) {
    $x=$key[0];
    $y=$key[1];
    $ges=$key[3];
    $t=$key[5];
    $data['x']=$x;
    $data['y']=$y;
    $data['ges']=$ges;
    $data['t']=$t;
    $alldata[]=$data;

}

$lastdata = json_encode($alldata);

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>gyroscope</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
        .circle {
            -moz-border-radius: 50% !important;
            border-radius: 50% !important;
            -webkit-border-radius: 50% !important;
            }

        .finger
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px; 
            left: 0px;
            background: #fb4c4c; 
            border: 2px solid #FF0000; 
            display: none;
            opacity: 0.6
        }
        .swipeup{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px; 
            left: 0px;
            display: none;
            width: 0; height:0; 
            border-bottom: 50px solid #FF0000;
            border-left: 25px solid transparent;
            border-right: 25px solid transparent;
            opacity: 0.6;}
        .swipeleft{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px; 
            left: 0px;
            display: none;
            width: 0; height: 0;
            border-right: 50px solid #FF0000;
            border-top: 25px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 25px solid transparent; 
            opacity: 0.6;}
        .swipedown{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px; 
            left: 0px;
            display: none;
            width: 0; height: 0;
            border-top: 50px solid #FF0000;
            border-left: 25px solid transparent;
            border-right: 25px solid transparent; 
            opacity: 0.6;}
        .swiperight{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px; 
            left: 0px;
            display: none;
            width: 0; height: 0;
            border-left: 50px solid #FF0000;
            border-top: 25px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 25px solid transparent; 
            opacity: 0.6;}
        </style>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var responsedata = '<?php echo $lastdata; ?>';

                alldata = JSON.parse(responsedata);
                console.log(alldata);
                //get mouse position inside div
                    $("#vediocontainer").bind("mousemove",function(e) {
                              var offset = $(this).offset();
                              var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
                              var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);

                            $("#result").html("x:" + relativeX + ", y:" + relativeY);

                        });

    var tap = '<div id="finger1" class="tap finger circle" style="display: none; width: 30px; height: 30px; left: 153px; top: 215px; opacity: 0.6;"></div>';
    var swipeup='<div id="swipeup" class="swipeup">';
    var swipedown='<div id="swipedown" class="swipedown">';
    var swipeleft='<div id="swipeleft" class="swipeleft">';
    var swiperight='<div id="swiperight" class="swiperight">';

            $(tap).prependTo($("#vediocontainer"));
            $(swipeup).prependTo($("#vediocontainer"));
            $(swipedown).prependTo($("#vediocontainer"));
            $(swipeleft).prependTo($("#vediocontainer"));
            $(swiperight).prependTo($("#vediocontainer"));


            var vid,time,prevtime = 0;
            x=0,y=0,ges="",t=0;

           $('#screenvideo').on('canplay', function()
           {
                vid = $('#screenvideo').get(0); 
           });

            $('#screenvideo').on('timeupdate', function(){
                time = Math.floor(vid.currentTime);

                    $.each(alldata, function(indexInArray) {

                        x = alldata[indexInArray].x;

                        y = alldata[indexInArray].y;

                        ges= alldata[indexInArray].ges;

                        t = alldata[indexInArray].t;

                    if(time == t && time !=prevtime)
                        {
                            if(ges == 0)
                            {
                                $(".tap").css("left",(x - 15) + "px");
                                $(".tap").css("top", (y - 15) + "px");
                                $(".tap").attr("id", "event"+t);

                                $('#event'+t).show(100,'', function(){
                                    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
                                });
                            }
                            else if(ges ==1)
                            {
                                $(".tap").css("left",(x - 15) + "px");
                                $(".tap").css("top", (y - 15) + "px");
                                $(".tap").attr("id", "event"+t);

                                $('#event'+t).show(100,'', function(){
                                    $(this).fadeOut(200);
                                    $(this).show(100);
                                    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
                                });
                            } 
                            else if(ges==2)
                            {
                                $(".swipeup").css("left",(x - 15) + "px");
                                $(".swipeup").css("top", (y - 15) + "px");
                                $(".swipeup").attr("id", "swipeup"+t);

                                $('#swipeup'+t).show(100,'', function(){
                                    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
                                });
                            }
                             else if(ges==3)
                            {
                                $(".swipedown").css("left",(x - 15) + "px");
                                $(".swipedown").css("top", (y - 15) + "px");
                                $(".swipedown").attr("id", "swipedown"+t);

                                $('#swipedown'+t).show(100,'', function(){
                                    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
                                });
                            }
                             else if(ges==4)
                            {
                                $(".swipeleft").css("left",(x - 15) + "px");
                                $(".swipeleft").css("top", (y - 15) + "px");
                                $(".swipeleft").attr("id", "swipeleft"+t);

                                $('#swipeleft'+t).show(100,'', function(){
                                    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
                                });
                            }
                             else if(ges==5)
                            {
                                $(".swiperight").css("left",(x - 15) + "px");
                                $(".swiperight").css("top", (y - 15) + "px");
                                $(".swiperight").attr("id", "swiperight"+t);

                                $('#swiperight'+t).show(100,'', function(){
                                    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
                                });
                            }
                            else if(ges==6)
                            {
                                function loop()
                                {
                                    $(".tap").css("left",(x - 15) + "px");
                                    $(".tap").css("top", (y - 15) + "px");
                                    $(".tap").attr("id", "event"+t);

                                    $('#event'+t).animate(function()
                                    {
                                        $(this).fadeOut('slow');
                                    });
                                }
                               loop();
                                }

                            prevtime = time;
                        }
            });
});
        });

</script>
<body style="margin: 0 !important;">
    <div style="width:320px; height:480px; position:relative; margin:0px auto"> 
        <div id="vediocontainer" style="width:250px; height:388px;">
            <video  id="screenvideo" preload="auto"  src="screen.mp4" controls="controls" width="250px">
                <source type="video/mp4" src="screen.mp4"> 
            </video> 
        </div>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us your full code or make an online demo like on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @RohanKumar full code has been submitted now help me to animate scroll event

Comment: **Haha!** I don't know if it was meant that way, but to me the: "Now help me to animate scroll event" sounded like a command. Incase it was, you should know that the people in this website are not free slave workers.

Comment: am so sorry if it sounds in harsh way... but i doesn't literally mean that... i humbly requested to active member to help me in this problem... :)